# Apache2 subdomain doesn't load content (mirrors main domain)

Tags: server, apache2

I have an Apache2 webserver running on Ubuntu right now. The main domain is working fine ([example.com](https://example.com)). I'm trying to add a subdomain ([subdomain.example.com](http://subdomain.example.com)), but I can't get it to work.

The DNS *is* all set up correctly. I can ping [subdomain.example.com](http://subdomain.example.com). But when I navigate to the URL, it just mirrors the main domain at [example.com](http://example.com).

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, I have two files: `001-subdomain.example.com.conf` and `999-example.com.conf`.

`001-subdomain.example.com.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com *.subdomain.example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain-access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin me@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com *.subdomain.example.com
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                   nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                   downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/subdomain.example.com/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
</Directory>
```

`999-example.com.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com *.*
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com *.*
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                   nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                   downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/example.com/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
</Directory>
```

However, the subdomain still doesn't have any content. It just mirrors the main site. And the right files *are* at `/var/www/subdomain.example.com/html`.

How can I set up the subdomain to load the correct content?

Answer (score 1):

Apache loads things alphabetically so, if the subdomain config is *after* the main domain, there is a good chance that requests to the subdomain are being incorrectly routed to the primary. Generally what I do with Apache is have the primary site last in a list of config files. For example:

```
/etc/apache/sites-enabled$ ll

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  2月  3 16:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096  1月 22 13:07 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34  1月 28 21:49 002-subdomain1.conf -> ../sites-available/002-subdomain1.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33  2月  3 16:33 003-subdomain2.conf -> ../sites-available/003-subdomain2.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32  1月 22 17:39 999-primary.conf -> ../sites-available/999-primary.conf
```

Each of the config files contain both a `ServerName` and `ServerAlais` line with wildcards where appropriate. This means a Subdomain `.conf` file might look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email.address
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1/html

        ServerName sub1.domain.com
        ServerAlias sub1.domain.com *.sub1.domain.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain1-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain1-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>...</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/subdomain1/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
</Directory>
```

The primary (and default) site, would have a `.conf` file that looks similar, but with a broader list in `ServerAlias` to catch any unexpected traffic:

```
        ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com *.*
```

This has worked quite well over the years

Comment: Does this mean I need to make a separate `.conf` file for the subdomain in `sites-available`, and then enable it using `a2ensite`?

Comment: Technically you don't *need to*, but it's something that I do to keep things visually cleaner and easier to maintain. If you want to have everything in the same `.conf` file, that's fine, but have your subdomains first, *then* the primary.

Comment: I've done everything that you suggested, but it's still not working. I updated the question with the new files. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled the site with `sudo a2ensite 001-subdomain.example.com.conf`? After enabling the site you'll need to restart (or reload) Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`. If you are still being redirected to the main site, check your Apache logs, because now you have one that is dedicated for the subdomain. See if you have accesses. if you do, then there could be a redirect in an `.htaccess` file or elsewhere.

Comment: Hm, there's nothing logged to the subdomain access or error logs. In the general `error.log`, though, this message is showing up: `subdomain.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`. Honestly I'm pretty lost now, that's suggesting there's a problem with the certificate? I did get rid of the `default-ssl.conf` file when reconfiguring the `.conf` files. It's not giving that error for the main domain.

Comment: The error you're referencing means that the SSL certificate you have defined in the `*:443` section of the subdomain record does not have a record for the subdomain, which makes it invalid.